# How to export Illustrator files as PDFs so that Illustrator's pixel measurements match the pixels in the exported file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resolution, pixel

The gray navbar shown in the Illustrator file below is 70 pixels high, in Illustrator:

[image: Illustrator]

However when exported as a PDF, viewed at 100% size, it becomes 108 pixels high:

[image: PDF]

How can I export it as a PDF (or some other non-Illustrator format) while keeping the exact pixels sizes that the Illustrator file had?

Comment: Is Acrobat's Pixel Density setting set to match your monitor (Page Display Preferences)? This is one of those things you can adjust on *your* system, but it may or may not be correct on *any* other system.

Comment: Both Illustrator and the PDF file format are firmly based in *real world meaurement units*. Neither have something called "pixels".. Perhaps you should design and view your artwork with pixel-based tools instead.

Comment: Actually..... Acrobat as a Pixel Density setting to control the size of PDFs on a monitor. Setting it too low may result in PDFs being displayed larger than they are at 100%, and setting it too high has the opposite effect.

Comment: @Scott: yes, and that is because there is no link between any individual screen's pixel size and the real world measurements from a PDF. Basically you have to *tell* it how many pixels go into a 1in line.

Answer (score 2):

Going to **Acrobat Preferences** > **Page Display** and setting the custom resolution to 72 
 pixels/inch, the measurements will match.

[image: Preferences]

[image: AI]

[image: Acrobat]

Comment: +1. `:)` I'd have posted similarly but for some reason my Acrobat version is crashing as soon as I tap "Page Display" in the preferences.